# keycloak unknown error while creating a new resource via rest api

Tags: api, keycloak

I am trying to create a new resource in keycloak
on keycloak UI I looged in with admin account then I created a realm called `demo` and a user `abc` in it and created a client `clientA` after that I have created a new resource named `resourceA` with scopes and policy and permissions
while on keycloak ui everything is working fine resource was created the user `abc` has realm roles as admin, uma_authorization and client role of the client `clienA` is uma_protection

when i try to create a resource via rest api i am getting `{"error":"unknown_error"}`

Here are the steps I am following
obtained a pat as shown [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/authorization_services/#_service_protection_whatis_obtain_pat)

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=clientA&client_secret=given client secret' \
    "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

I got the access token (pat) then I followed next [step](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/authorization_services/#creating-a-resource)

```
    curl -v -X POST \
      http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/authz/protection/resource_set \
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$here i am adding the pat i received from the previous step \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      -d '{
      "resource_scopes":[  
        "read-public",
        "post-updates",
        "read-private",
        "http://www.example.com/scopes/all"
      ],
      "icon_uri":"http://www.example.com/icons/sharesocial.png",
      "name":"Tweedl Social Service",
      "type":"http://www.example.com/rsrcs/socialstream/140-compatible"     
      }'
```

I got `{"error":"unknown_error"}` as a response with status code 400 Bad request. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Check the Keycloak logs. There will be exception. It can be for example wrong payload.

Comment: there is no logs in keycloak :(

Answer (score 1):

I know what it feels like :)

#### Reason

[org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/66dfa32cd569a7416de21b4dc04db212e8fccce5/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/error/KeycloakErrorHandler.java#L70) gets error text from `WebApplicationException::getMessage` method result.

```java
public Response toResponse(Throwable throwable) {
   //...
   error.setError(getErrorCode(throwable));
   //...
}
private String getErrorCode(Throwable throwable) {
    if (throwable instanceof WebApplicationException && throwable.getMessage() != null) {
        return throwable.getMessage();
    }

    return "unknown_error";
}
```

And if caused exception is another type of RuntimeException you will get `"unknown_error"`

#### Solution (short path):

1. Extend `WebApplicationException` and implement your own constructor and `getMessage` method like that:

```java
public class CustomException extends WebApplicationException {
    private final String message;

    public AbstractUserException(Throwable throwable) {
        // log exception if you want
        this.message = throwable.getMessage();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

2. Wrap the main code of your resource in the `try catch` block, which always will throw your custom Exception

```java
try {
    // your code
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new CustomException(e);
}
```

3. Voila! You will get a readable error in response

P.S. If you want to go further - you can throw your exception with a complete HTTP Response object, which may contain custom HTTP status code, etc